# Create a TouchList programmatically

Tags: android, layout, widget, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to use the TouchListView made available here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist. It's an Android library to create reorderable lists.

I can run the demo fine, but I can't find a way to create a TouchList in Java, ie without defining it in an XLM layout.

Here's the code from the demo:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TouchListView tlv=(TouchListView)getListView();
    adapter=new IconicAdapter();
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    tlv.setDropListener(onDrop);
    tlv.setRemoveListener(onRemove);
}
```

It's inside a ListActivity. That works fine. Now here what I've tried to avoid the use of a ListActivity:

```
...
TouchListView tlv = new TouchListView(this, null);
adapter=new IconicAdapter();
setListAdapter(adapter);
...
```

No luck.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
TouchListView tlv = (TouchListView) (inflater.inflate(R.layout.touchlistview, null));
```

Doesn't work either.

In both cases the list is displayed correctly but I can't move the items around.

Any idea?

Comment: Well, the first case won't work, as there are various attributes (see the `tlv` ones in the `demo/`) that are needed. The second one might work, depending on the contents of `R.layout.touchlistview`, if you eventually add the `TouchListView` to a parent container somewhere along the line.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that my grabber id was wrong :/ BTW, is there a way to have items of different sizes in the list? I have some multiline entries and they get resized to single line as soon as I move something.

Comment: Not really AFAIK. This code is just adapted from some stuff from the AOSP Music app, which didn't have varying-size rows. There is the notion of expanding a row when you drag over it -- I just updated the sample to better demonstrate that. However, I think the code assumes the rows are otherwise the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that you're not setting any of the attributes, as you pass in `null`.

By default the variable controlling the remove mode is set to `-1`, which equals `none` according to the xml file declaring the attributes.

```
private int mRemoveMode = -1;
```

and

```
<attr name="remove_mode">
    <enum name="none" value="-1" />
    ...
</attr>
```

The documentation states that `remove_mode=none` means that the user cannot remove any list entries.

Now, as far as I know, you cannot create an `AttributeSet` without using xml. If you really don't want to use *any* xml files, then you should probably adapt the `TouchListView` class and add the necessary getters and setters.